# how can i create a seekbar in javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, seekbar

i am working on a webapp for viewing youtube videos using chromeless and it js api

i can implement play,pause,mute,etc easily but not sure how to create a seekbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use/customize the [slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) control provided by jQuery UI to solve your problem

update: the code sample that you have requested in comment. The same sample is uploaded in http://elangovanr.com/samples/jquery/slider.html

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #slider { margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#slider").slider(
          {
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              step: 1,
              change: showValue

          });
          $("#update").click(function () {
              $("#slider").slider("option", "value", $("#seekTo").val());

          });
          function showValue(event, ui) {
              $("#val").html(ui.value);
          }
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
  <p>
  The jQuery UI Slider plugin makes selected elements into sliders. There are various options such as multiple handles, and ranges. The handle can be moved with the mouse or the arrow keys.
  </p>
  <p>
  This sample demonstrates the simple usage of the slider seek to function.
  For more information about slider, please procedd to http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider
  </p>
<div id="slider"></div>
Seek To : <input id="seekTo" type="text" value="10" />
<input id="update" type="button" value="Update" />
Current Value : <span id="val">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am new to jquery, didn't get you.
any example please

Comment: try this <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #slider { margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").slider();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
  
<div id="slider"></div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: check the demo and its source in the page http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider this might help you

Comment: i have a seekTo() function how can i implement it on slider

Comment: i have a seekTo(seconds) function how can i implement it on slider